# AspectJ using 2 Aspect files for a single Android project

Tags: android, aspectj

I have an Android application to be tested in Eclipse. I have 2 `pointcuts` to be executed. One is for all the methods and one for `onClickListener`. There are multiple packages in my Android project. The `pointcuts` are as follows -

```
 pointcut methodCalls():
          execution(* com.example.buttontestaspect..*(..)) ||  execution(* com.example.hello..*(..))  && !within(com.example.buttontestaspect.testbutton);

pointcut OnClickListener_onClick(View v) :
        execution(void OnClickListener.onClick(View)) && args(v);
```

If i use both the `pointcuts` in a single Aspect file, it is affecting the Android app launch due to multiple packages being tested in `pointcut` `methodCalls()`.

Hence I am planning to use 2 Aspect files for each `pointcut`. Is this fine or is there any other better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the answer by myself. I used 2 Aspect files for each pointcut and found out that there is no much use. To avoid this app crash, I found out a solution. Testing 1 package at a time and loading the next package after testing the previous one.